# Angular render custom component with pdf service when page is empty

Tags: angular, pdf, service, components

I have a simple application, where pages are displayed. Each page can have multiple contentItems (attachments) or can be empty. I have been searching for solution to render empty page component whenever the page that I click on is empty, but I can not seem to find any resource.

Do you know of any good resource I could look at or solution to my current function?

This is my service:

```
displayContent(contentPDF: ContentItem, pageNum: PageNumber): void {
    this.selectedItem = ContentItem;
    let displayedItem: PDFItem;
//This is working solution that displays content for each page
    if (contentPDF?.data) {
      displayedItem = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: atob(contentPDF.data)});
    } 
//This should display custom component saying page is empty
    else if (this.canvasPdf) {
      this.canvasPdf.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasPdf.width, this.canvasPdf.height);
      this.drawService?.canvas?.clear();
      //Here I need to display the default component
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't you use an *ngIf to hide/show your PDF/default component?

Comment: Hi Liam. As I think about it, yes, you are right. I specified boolean variable in the service and based on that I am rendering either content or empty page information. Thank you :)